# How to write a nightwatch.js test for keys that works for both Chromium and Firefox driver?

Tags: nightwatch.js

I'm trying to write a test for [Gridmapper](https://campaignwiki.org/gridmapper.svg). This is a an application that uses ordinary ASCII keys to control the application. I'm trying to write a test to determine whether 'w' does what it is intended to do. Sadly, I can't write a test that works for both ChromeDriver and FirefoxDriver.

This is how I accept key events in my app:

```
document.onkeydown = keyPressed; // capture arrow keys
document.onkeypress = keyPressed; // capture character keys
```

This is a test that works for Chrome:

```
module.exports = {
  'walls' : function (browser) {
    browser
      .url('file://' + process.cwd() + '/gridmapper.svg')
      .assert.elementPresent('#walls0')
      .keys('w')
      .waitForElementPresent('#wall_0_0', 1000)
      .end();
  }
};
```

This is the same test such that it works for Firefox:

```
module.exports = {
  'walls' : function (browser) {
    browser
      .url('file://' + process.cwd() + '/gridmapper.svg')
      .assert.elementPresent('#walls0')
      .sendKeys('#ui', 'w')
      .waitForElementPresent('#wall_0_0', 1000)
      .end();
  }
};
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried all sorts of combinations, tried sending the event to the document root element and a few more options, but I'm running out of ideas.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to get the browserName and that's stored in the capabilities object. You may or may not need to do further operations on the string, but toUpperCase *should* work.

You can add conditionals, you will just need to use the 'browser.' notation for each subsequent command.

Something like this should do the trick.

```
module.exports = {
  'walls' : function (browser) {
    var runtimeBrowser = browser.capabilities.browserName.toUpperCase()
    browser
      .url('file://' + process.cwd() + '/gridmapper.svg')
      .assert.elementPresent('#walls0')
      if(runtimeBrowser === "CHROME"){
          browser.keys('w') 
      } elseif(runtimeBrowser === "FIREFOX")  {
          browser.sendKeys('#ui', 'w')
      } else {
          // do other default thing
      }
      browser.waitForElementPresent('#wall_0_0', 1000)
      browser.end();
  }
};
```

Comment: The tokens `else` and `elseif` seem to be unsupported in my copy.

Comment: Why do you say that? what is the message you see?

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Comment: I can't think of why else and elseif would be problematic. I would expect the problem is more likely that a statement semi-colon was dropped, or that some other javascript syntactical concern came up.  I'm glad you found a solution (below), though.

Comment: `runtimeBrowser` should use === for comparison and `elseif` should be `else if` Just for anyone who finds this helpful.

Comment: Excellent point, ioedeveloper. I have updated the code snipet.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a way to do it so now I'm generating test files for Firefox from the test files for Chrome.

**nightwatch.json** uses two test directories:

```
{
  "src_folders" : ["tests/chrome", "tests/firefox"],
  "output_folder" : "reports",
  "custom_commands_path" : "",
  "custom_assertions_path" : "",
  "page_objects_path" : "",
  "globals_path" : "",

  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : true,
    "server_path" : "./bin/selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar",
    "log_path" : "",
    "port" : 4444,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "./bin/chromedriver",
      "webdriver.gecko.driver" : "./bin/geckodriver"
    }
  },

  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
      "selenium_port"  : 4444,
      "selenium_host"  : "localhost"
    },

    "chrome" : {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome"
      },
      "filter" : "tests/chrome/*.js"
    },

    "firefox" : {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "firefox",
        "marionette": true
      },
      "filter" : "tests/firefox/*.js"
    }
  }
}
```

**Makefile** allows me to run Chrome tests or Firefox tests. Firefox tests are generated from Chrome tests using a search and replace with sed:

```
chrome-test-files := $(wildcard tests/chrome/*.js)

firefox-test-files := $(patsubst tests/chrome/%,tests/firefox/%,$(chrome-test-files))

all:
    @echo "Did you want to run 'make tests'?"

test: test-firefox test-chrome

test-firefox: $(firefox-test-files)
    node_modules/.bin/nightwatch --env firefox

test-chrome: $(chrome-test-files)
    node_modules/.bin/nightwatch --env chrome

tests/firefox/%.js: tests/chrome/%.js
    @mkdir -p tests/firefox
    sed -e "s/\.keys(/.sendKeys('#ui',/" < $< > $@
```

And now it all works and I'm still disappointed that there was no easy answer within Nightshift.